# Random search vs. GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to use random search algorithm instead of grid search with scikit-learn. But I can only find GridSearchCV estimator in documentation. Is it possible to use random search instead of grid search in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random search was [added to the dev version](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/0c94b55c63fcd28a47b156cbc0cf331ec6d42a7a) 5 days ago, so yes you can, if you're willing to use the bleeding edge version. Otherwise, either wait for the next (0.14) release, or consider using [hyperopt](http://jaberg.github.com/hyperopt/).